# Return variable from php to flash is undefined

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

When I run the script the everything works fine except that the variables returned to flash are undefined. I understand this question has been asked before but I have looked at every forum I can possibly find with this problem and none of the solutions work. When I trace the variables they all come back "undefined"

Actionscript 3:

```
function CheckRegistration(event:Event):void{
    var ServerCheck:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http:mywebsite/phpfile.php");
    var CrossCheck:URLVariables = new URLVariables;
    var ServerReply:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
        ServerCheck.data = CrossCheck;
        ServerCheck.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        ServerReply.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        ServerReply.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, CheckResult);
        CrossCheck.Requester = String("request");
        CrossCheck.InFirstName = String(FirstName);
        CrossCheck.InLastName = String(LastName);
        CrossCheck.InDeviceID = String(DeviceID);
        ServerReply.load(ServerCheck);
        count++
    if(count >= 3){
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, CheckRegistration);
    }
    trace("Checking Registration")
}

function CheckResult(event:Event):void{
    var CheckVar = String(event.target.data.registration);
    if(CheckVar == "confirmed"){
        trace(CheckVar);
        RegisteredDevice = true;
        this.gotoAndStop(2);
    }else{
        trace(CheckVar);
        this.gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('myserver', 'my_DB', 'mypassword'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Connection Failure, Contact FS support' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connection Secure'; 
mysql_select_db(my_DB);

if($_POST['Requester'] == "request"){
    $DeviceID = $_POST['InDeviceID'];
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $success = "registration=confirmed";
    $failure = "registration=failure";

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myInfo");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
         $RecFirstName = $row['FirstName'];
         $RecLastName = $row['LastName'];
         $RecDeviceID = $row['DeviceID'];
    }

    if(($RecFirstName == $FirstName) || ($RecLastName == $LastName) || ($RecDeviceID == $DeviceID)){
        print "registration=confirmed";
    }else{
        print "registration=failure";   
    }
    mysql_close();
}else{
    print "registration=failure";   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the problem. I traced `event.target.data` and found that the `echo 'Connection Secure';` was adding onto the return url. I erased this and it worked.